What endpoint path should I use to get the session ID for Salesforce Classic?
I'm working on a project where I need to obtain the session ID (sid) for Salesforce Classic. In my automation tests, I skip the login part by retrieving sid from the /one/one.app endpoint path and setting them in the browser cookies. This works fine initially, but at a certain point during redirection, I encounter the following error: "sandbox.my.salesforce.com refused to connect."
I suspect the reason for this error is that the session ID (sid) for sandbox.my.salesforce.com is not set. When I manually log in and copy the sid from sandbox.my.salesforce.com, this error does not occur anymore. However, I am unsure of how to retrieve this sid in my automated tests.
For example, I've tried accessing endpoints such as /services/data/v54.0, /home/home.jsp, and /ui/setup/Setup for the URL .sandbox.my.salesforce.com/, but none of them seem to return the session ID in the response headers.
Interestingly, I've found that I can successfully obtain the session ID using the endpoint /one/one.app for the URL sandbox.lightning.force.com but it does not work for me.
Any guidance or suggestions on which endpoint path I should use to successfully obtain the session ID for Salesforce Classic on the sandbox.my.salesforce.com URL would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

There's a lot of ways to get a Session ID. It would be helpful if you describe the reason behind why you're trying to get this specific Session ID. See the X-Y Problem for more information. Would you please [edit] your question to include more background information?

Thank you for your advice. I have edited my question.
